# WHat are "neglected cases" in a new organization?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I've created a new organization on CRM 2015 and everything went dandy. Then, I attempted to create an additional one on the server and got the error listed below.

What on Earth are "*neglected cases*" in a **new organization**?

> 16:10:44|  Error| System.Exception: Publishing CRM reports failed. ---> Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Could not publish report 'Neglected Cases' due to the following error:  An error occurred while trying to add the report to Microsoft Dynamics CRM. Try adding the report again. If this problem persists, contact your system administrator. ---> Microsoft.Crm.CrmReportingException: An error occurred while trying to add the report to Microsoft Dynamics CRM. Try adding the report again. If this problem persists, contact your system administrator. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Error while loading code module: ‘Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RdlHelper, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RdlHelper, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.ReportingServices2005.ReportingService2005.CreateReport(String Report, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RuntimeReportServer.UploadReport(String path, Byte[] reportDefinition, String name, String description, Boolean overwriteExistingReport)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RuntimeReportServer.UploadReport(String path, Byte[] reportDefinition, String name, String description, Boolean overwriteExistingReport)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RuntimeReportServer.UploadReport(SRSReport report, String reportNameOnSrs, String name, String description, Boolean isSharedReport, Boolean overwriteExistingReport)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.ReportServiceInternal`1.UploadSRSReport(Guid reportId, String reportNameOnSrs, String name, String description, SRSReport srsReport, ExecutionContext context, Boolean isCustomReport, Boolean overwriteExistingReport)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.ReportServiceInternal`1.CreateInternal(IBusinessEntity entity, Boolean isScheduledReport, ExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.ReportPublisher.UploadReportInternal(IBusinessEntity report, Int32[] relatedEntitiesArray, Int32[] categoriesArray, Int32[] visibilitiesArray, Guid organizationId, Boolean isProvisioning)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.ReportSetupPublisher.UploadReportInternal(IBusinessEntity report, Int32[] relatedEntitiesArray, Int32[] categoriesArray, Int32[] visibilitiesArray, Guid organizationId, Boolean isProvisioning)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.ReportPublisher.UploadReport(String reportFolder, String reportName, String fileName, String description, Int32 languageCode, Int32[] categoriesArray, Int32[] relatedEntitiesArray, Int32[] visibilitiesArray, Object parentId, Guid signatureId, Version version, Guid organizationId, Hashtable reportsPublished, String reportNameOnSrs, Boolean isProvisioning)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.ReportPublisher.UploadReports(Guid organizationId, String reportFolder, Int32 languageCode, Int32 matchCategoryNumber, Int32 addCategoryNumber, IProgressEventSource progress, Boolean isProvisioning)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.ReportSetupPublisher.OnPublishFail(Exception exception, String message)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.ReportPublisher.UploadReports(Guid organizationId, String reportFolder, Int32 languageCode, Int32 matchCategoryNumber, Int32 addCategoryNumber, IProgressEventSource progress, Boolean isProvisioning)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.Utility.ReportsUtility.UploadReports(String orgUniqueName, String reportFolder, Int32 languageCode, Int32 matchCategoryNumber, Int32 addCategoryNumber, IProgressEventSource progress)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.RSPublishAction.PublishReports(String organizationUniqueName)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.RSPublishAction.Do()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---, Error, AbortRetryIgnore, Option1
>   16:10:51|   Info| InputResult: Ignore
>   16:10:51|   Info| CrmAction execution time; RSPublishAction; 00:00:34.6283317
>   16:10:51|  Error| Installer Complete: OrganizationCreator - Error encountered
>   16:10:51|   Info| Setting organization state.  New state = Enabled
>   16:10:51|   Info| Found the older table DBUpdateInstallInfo_V5, updating new table and deleting
>   16:10:51|   Info| GetDBUpdateRevisionThresholdForServer(): Threshold = 7.0.0000.3543.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Neglected Cases` is the name of a standard report that is published when you are creating a new organization (this report shows cases that have not been processed within a given time).

When you create a new CRM organization, the standard reports are published. The interesting detail about your error is this line:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RdlHelper'
```

It seems to me your installation is corrupt. Did you install the "Microsoft Dynamics CRM Reporting Extensions" on the SQL/Reporting server?